# "a computer hack with a compulsion", what does this mean?

Tags: meaning

> we gotta have a secure system. One that can’t be broken into by a
>   computer hack with a compulsion for industrial espionage.

I looked up compulsion, I understand it alone. But I can't understand it in the sentence.

Comment: I searched it again. Maybe, just its literal meaning. I'll delete this question later.

Comment: Did the speaker  mean **hacker**?

Comment: @马化腾 Could you please cite your source? It's probably a mistake. Only people can have a compulsion for something. Not things. A hack is a thing. A hacker is a person. I think that's what might have thrown you off as you were reading that passage. Am I right?

Comment: @MichaelRybkin sorry, It's from a novel Single White Woman. I can't find a online source. Since the book is relatively old, maybe some IT terms have changed.